# Why does one of my NVMe SSDs have high average response time, but only when copying older files?

Tags: windows, ssd

I have two SSD drives: SSD1 and SSD2, both internal, issue with SSD2.

Copying file "A" from SSD2 to SSD1 = average response time over 1 000ms, speed around 10 MB/s.

Then copying the same file "A" from SSD1 back to SSD2 = speed around 2GB/s.

After that, copying file "A" again from SSD2 to SSD1 = average response time 0.4ms, speed around 2GB/s.

When copying the first time, the SSD2 usage is 100% while reading only 10 - 30MB/s, the SSD is capable of 5GB/s read speed. The second time everything is fast and normal.

Basically every file saved on SSD2 before yesterday is extremely slow to "read", anything saved after is okay. Speeds in CrystalDiskMark as usual.

Is this a Windows issue? Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: I have two fast SSD drives on my  desktop and no speed issues on the desktop and none really from my fast (AC Wireless) laptop to / from the desktop. So I cannot say what the issue is for you, but it is not generally a Windows issue.

Comment: Could be due to SSD itself, it may have small portion of pseudo SLC in which it stores current data. So when data is first read, it's slow but gets put into the faster pseudo SLC portion from which it can be read faster when read a 2nd time. In addition 'old' data may read slow because of requiring more effort.

Comment: The SSD didn't use to have this issue before though. I even noticed when copying larger files, over 20GB the closer it gets to the end of the file, the faster it reads and after a while the problem disappears, until I copy another file. Also the write speed is still as it used to be, thus not affected.

Comment: Aha! So same config, same everything. Is drive fuller than before perhaps? Try figure out what's different rather than same as before when you did not experience the issue. I'd check SMART too, you never know if we can discover something from that. I agree issue sounds totally weird. Can you give model numbers, version Windows etc..